# In curvilinear relationship (inverted U shaped), how do we calculate the highest point?

Tags: regression

Let's assume that age and running performance have an inverted U-shaped relationship. How do I know at which age performance will be best?

Comment: Set the first derivative to 0 and solve for age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are an infinite number of U-shaped relationships, so it depends on your regression model.

If there's a lot of noise about the model, or few points you might fit something very simple like a quadratic function, and you can [estimate the maximum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64192/calculating-threshold-turn-value-using-mean-centered-quadratic-terms-in-regressi/64213#64213) from the fitted relationships. There are several ways you might form some kind of [interval for the location of the maximum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79967/estimating-95-confidence-interval-for-vertex-of-quadratic-fit/80072#80072). See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108522/compute-mode-of-a-quadratic-regression-with-confidence-intervals), and the discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40602/can-i-interpret-the-inclusion-of-a-quadratic-term-in-logistic-regression-as-indi) is also largely relevant.

If there's at least a moderate amount of noise  or a moderate amount of points, you may consider some kind of smooth function such as a local polynomial regression or one of a variety of spline models. There are some ways you might attempt to generate am interval for the maximum here also.

If there's very little noise or a very large number of points you can deal with rougher functions, such as ones containing some discrete jumps.

Comment: +1 It's valuable to look for an interval instead of just a point estimate.